# Jed editor hangs forever when invoked "indirectly"

Tags: tty, editors

I've tried a few console applications like `vim`, `mg`, `emacs`, `nano`, and `joe` as a `git` editor, and none of them seem to have any problems with being invoked "indirectly" like this (I don't know the actual term for starting an editor as a subprocess and then giving it control). `jed`, uniquely among editors I have tried, hangs forever with the message `loading /usr/local/Cellar/jed/0.99-19/jed/lib/emacs.sl` when it is launched indirectly via `git commit` or `ack <search term> --pager='jed'`. I've checked the file and it's there, it was installed as part of the `jed` formula on Homebrew on OS X.

I've tried running `git commit` and `ack ... --pager='jed'` and such under `bash` and `zsh` and both exhibit the same behavior.

I'm trying to get an understanding of the problem so I can configure my terminal/shell differently or, failing that, file a bug report. When an editor is launched from another program and takes control of the terminal, what exactly is happening? Since one of several pieces of software could be responsible for this strange behavior, how would I go about determining which component is behaving in a nonstandard way?

Comment: The obvious thing to check for (by reading its source-code) is whether `jed` checks if its standard input/output are a terminal, rather than a pipe (as suggested by `--pager`).

Comment: This bug has been fixed in the latest development snapshot of jed. http://www.jedsoft.org/snapshots/#jed

I'll update the homebrew formula after the next release.

Comment: This is fixed now when installing via `brew install --HEAD jed` seems like the formula itself is not up to date as I just ran into this after having installed via `brew install jed`

Comment: @Sideshowcoder Thanks for the `brew install --HEAD jed` tip! This bug still seems to exist in the default formula, `--HEAD` fixed it for me.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet Can confirm, fix works but homebrew is not updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known bug in the "current" (*) homebrew version of jed (0.99.19/Unix).

Try uninstalling jed and installing the latest development/pre version using:

```
brew uninstall jed
brew install --HEAD jed
```

This fixed the git/hang behavior for me on MacOS Ventura 13.5.2 (jed version pre0.99.20-180/Unix).

(*) This question is from 2016 and in 2023 the bug is still present in the current (homebrew) version.